# structure of the unit group modulo a prime power

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $m \geq 2$. Show that $\mathbb{Z}_{p^{m-1}} \times (\mathbb{Z}_{p})^{\times} = (\mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}})^{\times}$

I am having trouble coming up with the correct map that yields the desired result.  For starters I have considered the map $\phi:  \mathbb{Z}_{p^{m}} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_{p}$ with $\ker(\phi) = p\mathbb{Z}$.  But then I get stuck...

Comment: Conceptually, we want to find a way to split congruence classes of integers $n\pmod{p^m}$, coprime to $p^m$, into pairs as shown in a canonical way. Of course, $n$ is coprime to $p$, leaving a residue $r$ modulo $p$; $n-r$ is a multiple of $p$, so $(n-r)/p$ corresponds uniquely to a class modulo $p^{m-1}$.

Comment: @peoplepower, I think that with a little more polishing your comment can be a rather nice answer...

Comment: @peoplepower That is a very nice approach. But must the map be a homomorphism (assuming componentwise multiplication)?

Comment: @Aeolian Ah, so equality is not just set equality. Anyway, it does seem possible to do this with a collection of nonidentity maps $\mathbb Z_{p^{m-1}}\to Z_{p^m}$. However, when you derive them you see that it is just better to do a different approach anyway.